# Error in passing Array of more than 1000 records from one jsp to another

Tags: java, html, arrays, jsp

I am trying to pass an array of attributes(attributes of more than 1000 rows) from one jsp to another, but in the receiving jsp when traversing the array I am getting

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 999
```

error. This happens only when row count in calling jsp is more than 1000. I checked through debugger also, receiving jsp receives only 1000 records. Do we have any such limitation?

Calling jsp passes like this: For each row of data

```html
<input type="hidden" id='lines<%=j%>' name="lines" value="<%=claim.getBATCH_LINE_NO()%>" ></input>
<input type="hidden" id='claimids<%=j%>' name="claimids" value="<%=claim.getCLAIM_ID()%>" ></input>
```

Receiving jsp accesses like this:

```html
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    dto.setCLAIM_ID(request.getParameterValues("claimids")[i]);
    dto.setBATCH_LINE_NO(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameterValues("lines")[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ypu may want to choose sending also `count` value to receiving jsp and use its value to guarantee not to get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` like this way:

Sending jsp

```
<% int j = 0; %>
<% for(; j < claims.length; j++) { %>
<input type="hidden" id='lines<%=j%>' name="lines" value="<%=claim.getBATCH_LINE_NO()%>" ></input>
<input type="hidden" id='claimids<%=j%>' name="claimids" value="<%=claim.getCLAIM_ID()%>" ></input>
<% } %>
<input type="hidden" id='count' name="count" value="<%=j%>" ></input>
```

Receiving jsp

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("count"));
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    dto.setCLAIM_ID(request.getParameter("claimids" + i));
    dto.setBATCH_LINE_NO(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("lines" + i)));
}
```

Comment: The count used in my receiving jsp is passed exactly in the same way you have mentioned in the answer. But the issue is with large number of records. I have debugged and checked, count also passes correctly, but array has lesser number of records in receiving jsp.

Comment: What is the method of your form, is it 'post' or get